# Migrate SQL Server to Oracle 11G Offline (OMWB)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

So, I'm having some difficult to migrate SQL Server to Oracle. This time there appears a new error message:

```
Migration actions have failed check the migration reports for details. :
Capture 
Offline Capture 
ORA-00942: table or view do not exist.
```

I executed the `OMWB_OFFLINE_CAPTURE.bat`, I passed the parameter to batch and generated the directory with database related.

After, I executed **"Migrate To Oracle"** I caught the `sqlserver2008.ocp` file, I finalized, and that error mentioned above appeared. And it does not show the table or view nonexistent.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the script does not create things in the right order and it's trying to create  a view before the required table has been created. Have _any_ objects been created?

Answer (score 1):

The resolution is:

```
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, CREATE SESSION TO YOUR_USER
```

Or grant DBA Privilege

Before you granted the privileges, delete the repository associate and create again with new privileges or create the repository before you grant the privilege.

This way resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would suggest you to do is:

1. Connect to the Oracle DB with an Oracle User by which you are going to do Migration and running Import.
2. Try to create a table:

   CREATE TABLE M (
     t number
   );

If you get an error like: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` then you do not have Privileges to create a table, so that's why when you are trying to Migrate and running DDL commands it fails.

**Cause:**
You do not have right Privileges for the Oracle User.

**Solution:**
Grant privileges to your Oracle User (try with SYSDBA):

```
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO Your_Oracle_User;
```

I also mentioned CONNECT role here just in a case when you also do not have Privileges to connect with the Oracle User to your Oracle DB.

Comment: You had reason, the privileges was right but I forget to one detail, delete the repository and create again with new privileges of the user. Now gave right

Comment: @WelintonRibeiroJunior So, from the beginning the problem was related to the privileges, if you create a user with the right privileges and then move to other steps => then the problem should not arise. Hope I helped you.